# c++ function check true condition

Tags: c++

I make a function call and when it returns false, I continue to check indefinitely until it returns true. Is the following code is fine?

```
while(true)
{
  bool result = func();

  if(result == false)
    continue;
  else
    break;
}
```

Comment: "Check indefinitely" - ??

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: @Shumail Mohy-ud-Din It worked but I was looking nicer one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about getting rid of the `break` and `continue`. It is not considered very nice to use them (especially when not required):

```
bool result;
do
{
   result = func();

   if(result == false) {
      // Supposedly you want to do something here...?
   }
} while(result == false);
```

Of course you can use `!` instead of `false` to save some bytes in your source code. But I suppose that does not really matter at this point.

Comment: It's also not very nice to use expressions like `result == false`.  It's just `!result`.

Answer (score 4):

You could do that, but why not just:

```
while(!func())
{
    // do what you want to do...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use

```
while (!func());
```

instead? Some folk don't like to see an empty `while` and may therefore prefer @dwxw's solution.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with an empty `while` per se, but the controlled (empty) statement should be on a separate line, at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it shorter.

```
    do 
    {
    } while (!func());
```